# Facebook Authentication Window Does Not Close After Sign-In

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk, fbjs

I am using the fb:login button on my site here: http://www.stellarconquest.com/play.  This started recently -- in IE9 the authentication dialog does not close after successful sign-in.  Here is the link in the pop-up for the stranded window:

> "https://www.stellarconquest.com/channel.html?fb_xd_fragment#?=&cb=f171625b6c812fe&relation=opener&transport=fragment&frame=f30afb46b61a2a6&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&base_domain=stellarconquest.com"

I verified that this happens only if channel.html is used.  I'm not sure what changed to cause this.

Comment: what all do you have in the channel file?

Comment: @Shuan please dont expose your access_token and signed_request many one can able to misuse this

Comment: Hi Mike, here is my channel.html: [script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"][/script].  I replaced less than with [.